# PHP Syntax error: Unexpected for after string "</div>"

Tags: php

I been trying to figure out if I can add a `for loop` in this situation:

```
$g = '<td id="'.$this->currentDate.'" class=" td-top-text '.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
                ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'
                //if statement 
                .($this->currentDate === $tutor_date ? 
                    '<div class="inside">'//open inside
                        .'<div class="inside-content">' //open inside-content
                           . '<div class="inside-date">'.$cellContent.'</div>'//open and close inside-date



                             for($i =0; $i < count($appt_date['date']); $i++) {
                               '<div class="inside-event '.$bkg_color.' ck-button btn-xs" title="Group Session">'//open inside-event
                                   . '<label class="label-for-text">'//open label
                                       . '<input type="radio" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="appt_selected" value="'.$tutor_shedule_id.'" >'//open input
                                           . '<span>'.$tutor_info.'</span>' //open and close span
                                       .'</input>'// close input    
                                   . '</label>'// close label
                               . '</div>';//close inside-event
                           }


                           '</div>'//close inside-content
                       . '</div>'//close inside
                . '</td>' //close td


                //else
                : '<div class="inside">'.$cellContent.'</div>'
                  . '</td>' );

  return $g;
```

I tried so many things such as added a `;` at the end of `</div>` and before the `for loop`, I also added a `.` before the `for loop` and after.

**EDIT:**

Instead of down-vote this question, please provide some feedback and let me know what is wrong.  For me this code is "fine" until you tell me a better way to do it.  So, please I really appreciated your feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: uhm ... this code is a mess. You're missing a ";" before the for statement but, also, you cannot concatenate strings like this, especially if there are some if/while/for statements...

Comment: @DonCallisto Hii, please can you tell me how would you re-write this code?  I would love to see other way to do this.

Comment: And when I add `;` before the `for loop` I get an error `Unexpected: ; `

Comment: this is because you are still inside the `if-statement`.

Comment: I see ! ...good thanks for that

Comment: look at my answer below too. if you still get confused.

Comment: @ASK yesss im testing it.=)

Comment: *Salute To Your Courage For Writing Such A **Mess Code**. Really*

Comment: i've edited my answer you might want to check it.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Thank you Miss/Mr Perfect =)

Comment: did it solve your problem?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to do the `if-else` statement rather than this approach as this process is very difficult to debug. So, go with the following code:

```
    $g = '<td id="'.$this->currentDate.'" class=" td-top-text '.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">';

            if ($this->currentDate === $tutor_date){ 

                $g.='<div class="inside">'//open inside
                    .'<div class="inside-content">' //open inside-content
                       . '<div class="inside-date">'.$cellContent.'</div>';//open and close inside-date



                         for($i =0; $i < count($appt_date['date']); $i++) {
                           $g.='<div class="inside-event '.$bkg_color.' ck-button btn-xs" title="Group Session">'//open inside-event
                               . '<label class="label-for-text">'//open label
                                   . '<input type="radio" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="appt_selected" value="'.$tutor_shedule_id.'" >'//open input
                                       . '<span>'.$tutor_info.'</span>' //open and close span
                                   .'</input>'// close input    
                               . '</label>'// close label
                           . '</div>';//close inside-event
                       }



                      $g.= '</div>'//close inside-content
                   . '</div>'//close inside
            . '</td>' ;//close td

            }else{

             $g.='<div class="inside">'.$cellContent.'</div>'
              . '</td>'; }

  return $g;
```

Comment: I will, I just want to see if someone come up with other answers...but your was first and worked so ur will be the right one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well that was painful, I've tried to fix it up a little and at least make it more readable. Have a try of this... also I should point out I'm pretty sure this code is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

```
// Work out the Class names.
$classNameOne = ($cellNumber % 7) == 1 ? ' start '
                                       : ($cellNumber % 7) == 0 ? ' end'
                                                                : ' ';
$classNameTwo = ($cellContent == null) ? 'mask'
                                       : '';
// Build up the html.
$html = '<td id="' . $this->currentDate . '" class="td-top-text ' . $classNameOne .  $classNameTwo . '">';

if ($this->currentDate === $tutor_date) {
    $html .= '<div class="inside">';
    $html .= '<div class="inside-content">';
    $html .= '<div class="inside-date">' . $cellContent . '</div>';

    $dateInstances = count($appt_date['date']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $dateInstances; $i++) {
        $html .= '<div class="inside-event ' . $bkg_color . ' ck-button btn-xs" title="Group Session">';
        $html .= '<label class="label-for-text">';
        $html .= '<input type="radio" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal~ name="appt_selected" value="'. $tutor_shedule_id .'">';
        $html .= '<span>' . $tutor_info . '</span>';
        $html .= '</input>';
        $html .= '</label>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '</td>';

} else {
    $html .= '<div class="inside">' . $cellContent . '</div>';
    $html .= '</td>';
}

return $html;
```

Comment: damnn! I didn't know it was so bad guys, im really sorry!

Comment: @ArielMaduro Logically you were close to getting the right answer but your layout was sacrificing readability a lot which makes it a lot harder to find errors. The ternary operator can be useful, but you should be selective when you use it because otherwise it'll cause you headaches down the line when you return to the code/debug it. I'm not sure on the exact context of where you're returning it but remember to escape output otherwise you could get some nasty people breaking things.

Comment: i recommend code at your ease but just work a bit on the documentation of the code by maybe using spaces, blank lines,etc

Comment: @VirtualPigeon yes! I was getting the right data, I was adding the `for loop` just to pull out more than one `event` and I realize that something was wrong!